# Programmatically mute an Android wearable

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I programmatically want to mute the entire watch. So I wanted to do these things:
1. Mute to on , so go into non vibration mode. Will manufacturers be able to add sound capabilities to watches? Otherwise I would also have to add muting of sound...
2. Screen always on , to off. It's a system setting. Can I change it programmatically?

I already tried for point one to use the MediaManager:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

I tried all other ringer modes also just to be sure and nothing seems to work and change anything in the emulator and on my real watch but nothing is doing the job...

A pebble watch has night or silent mode support... So I won't be that hard to do it on a wearable I thought.. Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0):

> Wear 5.0.1 has some ability! the SDK sample Watchface has a way to detect it. Look for WatchFaceService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE - RoundSparrow hilltx

from this question here: [Android Wear detect "Mute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24763403/android-wear-detect-mute)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with [requestInterruptionFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#requestInterruptionFilter(int)) where fitler mode are:

- INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL
- NTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE
- INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY