# Android Wear detect "Mute"

Tags: java, android, wear-os

How does an application check in on "Mute" status of an Android Wear device?

All volumes seem t be 0 no matter what.

```
Log.d("VOLUME - STREAM_SYSTEM", Integer.toString(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM)));
Log.d("VOLUME - STREAM_NOTIFICATION", Integer.toString(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)));
Log.d("VOLUME - STREAM_RING", Integer.toString(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING)));
```

gives me

```
D/VOLUME - STREAM_SYSTEM(32598): 0
D/VOLUME - STREAM_NOTIFICATION(32598): 0
D/VOLUME - STREAM_RING(32598): 0
```

Comment: Newer Wear 4.4W2 supports playback of Audio directly via a Bluetooth headset.  So there must be a volume control now for that?  I see your post is July 15 2014 - you might want to re-visit the values...

Comment: Wear 5.0.1 has some ability! the SDK sample Watchface has a way to detect it. Look for WatchFaceService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Google has not seen fit to expose this to us lowly developers at this time as far as I can tell.

Thanks to the research of a friend of mine, Ive found this code.

```
public static boolean inZenMode(Context paramContext)
  {
    return paramContext.getSharedPreferences("home_preferences", 0).getBoolean("in_zen_mode", false);
  }
```

Zen mode is what Google calls the mute state, and currently you can only access that value with root by directly reading that file. Hopefully with an update in the near future, google will expose this value to us.

Comment: Google has now released source for Wear here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4w_r1  I'm not familiar enough with the Android source to track this down; anybody else up for the challenge?

Comment: Wear 5.0.1 has some ability! the SDK sample Watchface has a way to detect it. Look for WatchFaceService.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE

Answer (score 1):

Did you try these? It looks like you're looking for VOLUME, which doesn't exist in Android Wear. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11985560/1539431

Comment: I've tried that - doesn't work. audio.getRingerMode() always returns 0.

Comment: Ah. Then I am all out of ideas for now.

Comment: I lied, totally not out of ideas. It's probably not using any of that. There's probably a listener service on the phone that simply says `if(muted) return;` or something. You might need to think out of the box and bit more; try looking at the logs when you mute/unmute your wearable as well as the phone. A lot of Wearable logs are there, so you might be able to find a solution from that.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I'm also curios about the solution (not to use it, just curiosity:). I've tested many ways of detecting it already. I've tested listening for PHONE_STATE, checked the diffs for API 20, but found nothing so far. There are no logs in logcat on Wear, and no related (IMO) logs on phone.

Comment: Ive watched logs on phone and device, i think its gotta be something that just hasnt yet been exposed yet :'(